# How to understand this use of " the"

Tags: grammaticality, articles

It's a file in the game Resident EVIL 2 remake.

> T-Virus Resistance Experimentation
>
> (Subjects 628, 639)
>
> We administered G-Virus to subject 628, who had shown slight resistance to the T-Virus.  The* virus was then introduced to subject 639, with whom 628 had a close relationship. 628 showed some signs of resistance, but had been implanted with an embryo after 24 minutes. T-Virus resistance does nothing to stop the mental deterioration caused by the G-Virus.

I have marked it with *. In the Chinese translation, the virus refers to the T virus, but I don't quite understand why.

Comment: It refers to the G-Virus. They're administering G-Virus to two different people, one with resistance to T-Virus, and someone else.

Comment: If the "T-virus" had been mentioned and clearly established as the topic of the passage, there might be some ambiguity as to what "the virus" refers to. (It would be bad writing, but not an uncommon fault.) But without that context, it's definitely referring to the G-virus.

Comment: The reference would be clearer had the second sentence been one of the following: "The former was then introduced to subject 639 . . .", which would be a reference to the G-Virus; or "The latter was then introduced to subject 639 . . .", which would be reference to the T-Virus.

Answer (score 1):

> In the Chinese translation, the virus refers to the T virus,

If so, then the Chinese translation is wrong.

1. The use of "the" is licensed by the previous mention of G-Virus and *"The" virus was then introduced to subject 639"* = "The" G-Virus was then introduced to subject 639.
2. the clause *"who had shown slight resistance to the T-Virus"* is parenthetical/non-defining and can be omitted without significant loss of meaning.

Comment: Thank you so much! It hepls me a lot!